# Permission Denied while trying to connect to Docker Daemon while running Jenkins pipeline in Macbook

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run Jenkins pipeline job in my macbook. I also have docker instance running locally. Initially I got the "**docker command not found**" error while running the Jenkins Job. I fixed the error by adding a symlink "**ln -f -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/* /usr/local/bin**"

I also applied these two changes so that jenkins user has the access to the docker directory

1. chmod -R 777 /Users/myUserName/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/
2. chmod -R 777 /Users/myUserName/Library/Containers/com.docker.helper/

**I am getting below errors**:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.27/containers/openjdk:8/json:
>   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
>       [Pipeline] sh
>       [test] Running shell script
>       + docker pull openjdk:8
>       Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket
>   at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.27/info: dial unix
>   /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied). Using system
>   default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
>       Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.27/images/create?fromImage=openjdk&tag=8:
>   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
>       [Pipeline] }
>       [Pipeline] // node
>       [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>       ERROR: script returned exit code 1
>       Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket-at-uni)

Comment: Beware of this. It never hurts to say that if you do chmod without really knowing what you do, you may be creating a security hole. 777 means anybody has full read and write access to a resource. That's probably not necessary in most situations. In general, looking for a way to adjust the user's permissions (group memberships) rather than widening a resource availability, usually makes more sense.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can try this and worked for me:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -p 4040:4040 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home logimethods/jenkins
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. But this answer would have been of help to other people if it explained what's the purpose of the different arguments in that command line, and how each of them may affect the outcome.

Comment: This is absolutely NOT the correct solution. I'm very skeptical that this alone fixed your issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are any ways to solve this issue, I faced it last week, I solved but with `docker-compose` this setup is replicable to `docker`, you can create a shared volume that points from the location of `docker.sock` in your host `/var/run/docker.sock` to location of `docker.sock` in your container `/var/run/docker.sock`. Something like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: ./jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - /usr/local/bin/docker-compose:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    container_name: "prueba"
    links:
      - jenkins
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
```

To works well you have to give permissons of user to the `socket``sudo chown $USER:$USER /var/run/docker.sock` and to the group of `docker` , as [Innocent Anigbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7975584/innocent-anigbo) mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I applied the following changes to my system: 1. Create a docker group- "sudo dscl . -create /groups/docker". 2. Assign jenkins user to docker group- "sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a jenkins -t user docker". 3. Assign the socket to docker- "sudo chown jenkins:jenkins /var/run/docker.sock". But still seeing the same issue.

Comment: now, set up shared volumes, add this with docker run command  ```-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution: -**

Here is how I fixed the issue, open the terminal and type this command

`sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: This works well inside the Jenkins docker container (my case), otherwise it is not secure as everyone now has access to docker.

Answer (score 1):

This is a docker permission issue. Add the jenkins user to docker group as follow:

`usermod -aG docker ${USER}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, I don't have usermod command in mac

Comment: This _usermod_ step is suggested in Docker's [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/) and so it may still be relevant in Linux situations.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat hacky workaround:

- `DockerUser` is the user who installed Docker
- Both `DockerUser` and the Jenkins user are in the `staff` group (verify with `groups USERNAME`)

As `DockerUser`:

```
$ chmod g+rx /Users/DockerUser/Library
$ chmod g+rx /Users/DockerUser/Library/Containers
$ chmod g+rx /Users/DockerUser/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
$ chmod g+rw /Users/DockerUser/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.sock
```

> ⚠️ **Security Implications**
>
> Any user account on the machine (not just the Jenkins user) has write
> access to all of your docker containers/volumes/anything and launch
> anything they like.

Then as your other (Jenkins) user, you should be able to do the following to launch a container:

```
$ docker run --rm ubuntu uname -a
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
6a5697faee43: Pull complete
ba13d3bc422b: Pull complete
a254829d9e55: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:fff16eea1a8ae92867721d90c59a75652ea66d29c05294e6e2f898704bdb8cf1
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest

Linux dc3d34c548e5 5.4.39-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri May 8 23:03:06 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jenkins build agent user to the docker group and then restart jenkins for this to take effect:

```
usermod -aG docker ${USER}
systemctl restart jenkins
```